# Cannot load .cubin module in CUDA Driver API

Tags: cuda

I am using 0.3.1 JCuda and 3.1 nvidia cuda sdk. I am trying to run JCudaRuntimeDriverMixSample.java from [here](http://www.jcuda.de/samples/samples.html).  I compiled the .cu file with "nvcc -keep invertVectorElements.cu". I set the cuModuleLoad filename to the .sm_10.cubin file generated.
When I run the compiled java file, I get CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_SOURCE. I am running nvidia driver version 256.53 on a GTS 450 gpu.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried loading the `.ptx` file rather than the `.cubin` file? As I understand it, `.cubin` files are already assembled for very particular architectures, whereas `.ptx` are JIT-compiled by the driver. (You can still use `cuModuleLoad` with `.ptx`). You're attempting to load the `sm_10` version of the cubin - but do you have a compute capability 1.0 device?